# Trouble using VarImpPlot in randomForest R

Tags: r, random-forest

I built a RandomForest model using the following code:

```
library(randomForest)

set.seed(101)
RFs1 = ERC[sample(nrow(ERC),100000),]
RFs2  <-  RFs1[,-c(1,2,3,228,229,230,232,233,234,235,240)] 
RFs2 <- RFs2[complete.cases(RFs2),] # handling missing values

RFfit <- randomForest(as.factor(RFs2$earlyR)~., data=RFs2[,-231])

VI_F <- importance(RFfit)
varImpPlot(VI_F, type = 2)
```

Now, When I'm trying to plot `Feature Importance` I'm getting the following error:

> Error in varImpPlot(VI_F, type = 2) : 
>     This function only works for objects of class `randomForest'

I looked for a solution for the problem here (Stack Overflow) and over the net, buy I couldn't find one.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Tough to say without sample data, but you can try including the argument `importance = TRUE` in your call to `randomForest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with the code which I'll try to explain. I will do this with `mtcars` since you did not provide sample data. First, you need to pass `importance = TRUE` in your call to `randomForest`.

`mtrf <- randomForest(mpg ~ . , data = mtcars, importance = TRUE)`

You can get the `importance` as a table with

`importance(mtrf)`

```
> importance(mtrf)
       %IncMSE IncNodePurity
cyl  11.584480    194.396219
disp 12.560117    230.427777
hp   12.908195    201.095073
drat  5.238172     69.766801
wt   12.449930    233.921376
qsec  3.705991     27.621441
vs    4.221830     27.044382
am    1.982329      9.416001
gear  3.472656     18.282543
carb  6.116177     28.398651
```

However, to do the plot, you need to call `varImpPlot` on the actual `randomForest` object you created, using the `importance = TRUE` argument.

```
varImpPlot(mtrf)
```

[image]

I would recommend [Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) as a good intro to using the `randomForest` package in `R`.

Comment: First of all Thank you very much. If you don't mind, I'd like to ask you about some other thing related to the code above: when I'm running the code with `RFs2 <- RFs2[complete.cases(RFs2),]` and with `RFs3 <- RFs2[complete.cases(RFs2),]`, I'm getting different varImpPlot results. You have any idea what is the reason for that?

Comment: You might need to run `set.seed(1)`. `randomForest` does use random numbers, so if you want the results to be reproducible, you'd need to set the random number generator.